# Consulta SQL desde python no devuelve toda la tabla

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

actualmente en mi SQLite, tengo una tabla **Person** como la siguiente:

[image: Tabla persona con los campos ID y nombre]

Y otra tabla **Age** como la siguiente:

[image: Tabla Age con los campos ID y Edad]

La tabla **Person** la recorro con el siguiente método:

```
def print_tabla_person(cursor):
    for fila in SQL_generate("SELECT * from Person;",cursor):
        print(fila)
```

y la tabla **Age** la recorro con este otro método:

```
def print_tabla_age(cursor):
    for fila in SQL_generate("SELECT * from Age;",cursor):
        print(fila)
```

Mi problema radica en que la tabla **Person** la muestra entera y la tabla **Age** solo muestra 3 campos de todos los que tiene (más de 40)

¿Por qué me pasa eso? (No me sirve como respuesta unir las tablas, están así a propósito)

Gracias

---

Actualizo:

**método SQL_generate**

```
import apsw
def SQL_generate(sql,cursor): #Ejecuta la sentencia sql
    return cursor.execute(sql)
```

Si creo un script nuevo solo con la consulta a **Age** me muestra todo correctamente.

Comment: Y qué hace `SQL_generate()`? quizás el problema esté ahi. ¿Qué librería usas para acceder a la base de datos?

Comment: @abulafia He actualizado, gracias por el aviso

Comment: ¿cuántos registros tiene Person y cuántos Age?

Comment: @Carmen **person** tiene 63 registros y **Age** tiene 15

Comment: Prueba a hacer solo la segunda consulta sin la primera y si printa todas las tuplas puede que necesites limpiar cursor o usar un segundo cursor

Comment: @Carmen en mis pruebas hago primero la consulta a **Age** y sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: @XBoss a ver si alguien tiene otra idea, no veo el problema. Lo último que se me ocurre es que el dato en que se para (si es siempre el mismo) este dando el problemas, por si acaso puedes probar a hacer el select sobre elementos posteriores (con id mayor).

Comment: Pues parece ser problema de caché, que pese a que actualizaba la BD correctamente, supongo que en la caché estaría almacenada una antigua. He puesto la DB en otra carpeta del PC y ahora funciona bien :/